# I need to keep a table of check boxs checked

Tags: php, checkbox, html-table, session-variables

I have created a 2d array in combination with an embedded loop to create a table of check boxes, How can I keep the boxes checked after the user clicks the submit button? I suspect a session variable to be necessary but I am not sure how to implement that to this code. This is for a class project in which we are supposed to create a battleship game. Nobody in class has been able to assist me with this issue. Keep in mind that this is for an introductory class so don't expect me to know much when you submit an answer. Here is the some of the code for creating the board. If you need more than this let me know.

```
function createBoard(){
    //building the arrays
$column1 = array(
'a1','a2','a3','a4','a5','a6','a7','a8','a9','a10'
);
$column2 = array(
'b1','b2','b3','b4','b5','b6','b7','b8','b9','b10'
);
$column3 = array(
'c1','c2','c3','c4','c5','c6','c7','c8','c9','c10'
);
$column4 = array(
'd1','d2','d3','d4','d5','d6','d7','d8','d9','d10'
);
$column5 = array(
'e1','e2','e3','e4','e5','e6','e7','e8','e9','e10'
);
$column6 = array(
'f1','f2','f3','f4','f5','f6','f7','f8','f9','f10'
);
$column7 = array(
'g1','g2','g3','g4','g5','g6','g7','g8','g9','g10'
);
$column8 = array(
'h1','h2','h3','h4','h5','h6','h7','h8','h9','h10'
);
$column9 = array(
'i1','i2','i3','i4','i5','i6','i7','i8','i9','i10'
);
$column10 = array(
'j1','j2','j3','j4','j5','j6','j7','j8','j9','j10'
);
//build the master array
$row = array(
"a"=>$column1,
"b"=>$column2,
"c"=>$column3,
"d"=>$column4,
"e"=>$column5,
"f"=>$column6,
"g"=>$column7,
"h"=>$column8,
"i"=>$column9,
"j"=>$column10
);
    print<<<HERE
    <form method = "post"
        action = "">
    <table border = "1">

    HERE;
    for ($i="a";$i<="j";$i++){
    print "<tr>";
    foreach ($row["$i"] as $chkRow){

    print "<td><input type = 'checkbox' name = '$chkRow' value = '$chkRow'/>$chkRow</td>\n";
    }//end foreach
    print"</tr>\n";
    } //end for loop

    print "</table>";
    print "<button type = 'submit'>Fire!</button></form>";

    } //end function
```

Comment: You know which items are checked based on the POSTed values right?  So now you just need to evaluate these posted values against the full array of values and for those that are checked, output `checked="checked"` in the element

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, off the top of my head, but should be the basis of buiding a grid of checkboxes and keeping them checked as more things are added/removed from the grid.

```
<?php
session_start();
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $_SESSION['shots'] = $_POST['shots'];
}

echo '<form method="post"><table>';
for($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++) {
   echo '<tr>';
   for ($j = 'a'; $j <= 'j'; $j++) {  // this works, but you shouldn't not be doing "math" on characters
      $has_shot = isset($_SESSION['shots'][$i][$j]) ? ' checked="checked"' : '';
      echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='shots[$i][$j]'$has_shot /></td>";
   }
   echo '</tr>'
}
echo '</table><input type="submit"></form>';
```

Comment: I just updated my question to include the arrays. That should explain why I used 'a' through 'j' rather than 1-10 on my for loop.